# Is it possible to have a constructor template with no parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, function-templates

I wish to have a non-template class with a template constructor with no arguments.

As far as I understand, it's impossible to have it (because it would conflict with the default constructor - **am I right?**), *and the workaround is the following:*

```
class A{
   template <typename U> A(U* dummy) {
       // Do something
   }
};
```

Maybe there is a better alternative for this (or a better workaround)?

Comment: I would echo Johannes question. Why? There could be a better technique if we understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Loki It would be nice to have if generating something from a sequence of inputs (like vector's templated iterator constructor).

Comment: @VF1 Exactly why I came here. My class holds a vector of enums and I'd like to initialize it with a sequence of some kind. A vector seems heavy-weight, particularly pre-brace-init (C++98 here). VAR_ARGS seems just terrible (even though it may be best). Passing a reference to an array seems ok.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

There is no way to explicitly specify the template arguments when calling a constructor template, so they have to be deduced through argument deduction.  This is because if you say:

```
Foo<int> f = Foo<int>();
```

The `<int>` is the template argument list for the type `Foo`, not for its constructor.  There's nowhere for the constructor template's argument list to go.

Even with your workaround you still have to pass an argument in order to call that constructor template.  It's not at all clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It MAY be possible with qualifed constructor call, but seems does not work: Foo<int>::Foo<short>();

Comment: But automatic type inference is still possible. As long as you are satisfied with automatic type inference, you can use a template constructor (of a non-template class).

Comment: @updogliu:  Absolutely.  But, the question is asking about "a template constructor with no arguments"  If there are no function arguments, no template arguments may be deduced.

Answer (score 49):

You could use a templated factory function instead of a constructor:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    template <class T> static Foo* create() // could also return by value, or a smart pointer
    {
        return new Foo(...);
    }
...        
};
```

Comment: But what about normal objects.

Comment: @Martin: I think this could also return by value (a non-pointer). RVO should take care of eliminating the copy anyway.

Comment: create() does not have to do dynamic allocation. Just `return Foo(...);`  Thanks @Samuel_xL.  This turned out to be a great idea for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, factory methods do not return xref values.. xref can be used with && with additional std::move.. if they *did/could*..

Comment: I don't get. How does it call a templated constructor with an empty parameters list? It seems to call regular one.

Answer (score 28):

```
template<class...>struct types{using type=types;};
template<class T>struct tag{using type=T;};
template<class Tag>using type_t=typename Tag::type;
```

the above helpers let you work with types as values.

```
class A {
  template<class T>
  A( tag<T> );
};
```

the `tag<T>` type is a variable with no state besides the type it caries.  You can use this to pass a pure-type value into a template function and have the type be deduced by the template function:

```
auto a = A(tag<int>{});
```

You can pass in more than one type:

```
class A {
  template<class T, class U, class V>
  A( types<T,U,V> );
};
auto a = A(types<int,double,std::string>{});
```

Comment: I see these `types`, `tag`, `type_t` templates or variants of it quite often in all sorts of contexts. Is there something in `std` for this?

Comment: @thorink No, which is why I write them.  Boost Hana has value-based metaprogramming if I recall correctly, which is close?

Comment: There exists a nice trick for a) more performance (`constexpr`) and b) avoiding the need to explicitly instantiate an object using `{}`: Use a templated inline constexpr object like `template<typename _Tp>  inline constexpr in_place_type_t<_Tp> in_place_type{};` in `<utility>` header. Check the example on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant) where they use `std::in_place_type<std::string>` to pass a `constexpr` tag object without explicit instantiation "`{}`".

Comment: @phinz Do you have proof of more performance, or do you just suspect?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont It is clear that `constexpr` is easier to optimize but to be honest I think that most compilers will optimize away both objects completely in this case. But why else should `in_place_type` be `constexpr` if it was not meant to be an optimization hint for compilers?

Answer (score 27):

> As far as I understand, it's impossible to have it (because it would conflict with the default constructor - am I right?)

You are wrong. It doesn't conflict in any way. You just can't call it ever.

Comment: 1. Actually, you can call the template ctor: `int *p; A a(p)`. 2. Prejudice or idealization ;-) There is no John Doe. There is nothing typical German... and definitely not in Johannes' words. If they sound humorless then just because C++ is humorless.

Comment: @AndreasSpindler I meant that he can never call the constructor if it has no arguments but still a template parameter (applies only to C++03. C++11 has introduced default template parameter, which would allow calling it, of course, if the ctor has default arguments..).

Answer (score 19):

Some points:

- If you declare **any**
  constructor(including a templated
  one), the compiler will refrain from
  declaring a default constructor.
- Unless you declare a copy-constructor (for class X one
  that takes `X` or `X&` or `X const
  &`) the compiler will generate the
  default copy-constructor.
- If you provide a template constructor for class X which takes
  `T const &` or `T` or `T&` then the
  compiler will nevertheless generate a
  default non-templated
  copy-constructor, even though you may think that it shouldn't because when T = X the declaration matches the copy-constructor declaration.
- In the latter case you may want to provide a non-templated copy-constructor along with the templated one. They will not conflict. When X is passed the nontemplated will be called. Otherwise the templated

HTH

Comment: Funny thing is that if you declare sometihng like template <typename T> X(const X&); then it still will not be recognized as copy constructor, and standard copy-constructor will be created.

Comment: @j_kibik: Yes, the same is about templated assignment

Comment: ...and default ctors. A class declared as `struct S { template<typename T> S() { } };` declares an "unreachable ctor". There is no way to deduce or pass the `T`. Nonetheless a default ctor is not generated since a user-defined ctor seems to exist.

Answer (score 4):

It is perhaps easier and more intuitive to rely on [`std::in_place_type_t<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/in_place) which is used in `std::variant`, `std::any`, etc for exactly the same purpose:

```cpp
#include <utility>

class A {
   template <typename U>
   A(std::in_place_type_t<U>) {
       // Do something
   }
};

A a(std::in_place_type_t<MyType>{});
```

Comment: Instead of `std::in_place_type_t<MyType>{}` one should use `std::in_place_type<MyType>`, it's a templated inline constexpr object defined exactly for this purpose, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant) for an example using `std::in_place_type<std::string>`.

Comment: @phinz This is accurate, thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
class C 
{
public:
    template <typename T> C(T*);
};
template <typename T> T* UseType() 
{
    static_cast<T*>(nullptr);
}
```

Then to create an object of type `C` using `int` as the template parameter to the constructor:

```
C obj(UseType<int>());
```

Since you can't pass template parameters to a constructor, this solution essentially converts the template parameter to a regular parameter. Using the `UseType<T>()` function when calling the constructor makes it clear to someone looking at the code that the purpose of that parameter is to tell the constructor what type to use.

One use case for this would be if the constructor creates a derived class object and assigns it to a member variable that is a base class pointer. (The constructor needs to know which derived class to use, but the class itself doesn't need to be templated  since the same base class pointer type is always used.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround.

Make a template subclass B of A. Do the template-argument-independent part of the construction in A's constructor. Do the template-argument-dependent part in B's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

try doing something like

```
template<class T, int i> class A{

    A(){
          A(this)
    }

    A( A<int, 1>* a){
          //do something
    }
    A( A<float, 1>* a){
         //do something
    }
.
.
.
};
```

Comment: this can also be done with template functions by defining a non-template class, a template constructor which is called from a non-template default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple to add a dummy variable like

```
class A {
  template<typename T>
  A(const T&, int arg1, int arg2);
}
```