# when we need to provide template parameters to define a class?

Tags: c++

```
template<typename T> class A // template parameterization
{
   private:
      T t;
   A(const T& v) : t(v) {}
};

class B
{
    template<typename T>
    B(const T& v)
    {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
};

// usage of A and B
A<int> a;
B      b(10);
```

Question> In what circumstances, we have to provide template parameters in order to define a class variable.

For example,

If the class contains a template member variable or ???

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide template parameters to create an instance if the class is a class template. In your example, `class A` is a class template, and `class B` isn't.

Class template:

```
template <typename T> class A {};
```

Not a class template:

```
class B { 
  // code may include function template, etc.
  // but the class itself is not a class template
};
```

In your example, `class B` has a template constructor, and the argument can be used by the compiler to determine which specialization to make. So in this case, it generates a constructor equivalent to

```
B(const int&);
```

because the literal `10` is an `int`. Constructors are not like functions, so this can only work if the compiler can figure out what `T` is. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960849/c-template-constructor) for more details.

Comment: +1 for putting it together in better words than i could.You could also add a detail as to why it is not necessary for specifying a type while creating the object in second case, eventhough the constructor is a template function.I see the Q now and I think that was the purpose of the Q.

Comment: @Als I tried to explain the latter point in an edit. It is complicated, because one cannot tell the compiler what T is in the case of a constructor...

Comment: Exactly and that is what the OP seems to be after. I realized it pretty much after i posted but saw your answer was much better than mine and could be even better if explained that detail.Just that, you already have my +1. :)

Comment: I'd say that `class A` is a class template. `A` is not a class, so it's somewhat misleading to call it a template class.

Comment: @SteveJessop thanks, I agree entirely. I realise both terms are used, but `class template` is more accurate.