# C++ how to call templated constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

How can I change the code below to allow creation of a Base object
with a templated constructor?

```
struct Base {
template <typename T>
Base(int a) {}
};

 int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Base *b = new Base<char>(2);
    delete b;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

This thread seems to answer your question:

[C++ template constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960849/c-template-constructor)

The bottom line is that it doesn't seem to be supported; and it's unclear what it would achieve.

Comment: Sometimes constructors handle many types but the data is only used temporarily, so having the class itself be templated is reduntant. There's not a huge need for it I guess but it makes sense.

Answer (score -5):

The question is a bit vague.  Is your intent to replace the "int a" in the Base ctor with "T a"?  If so, you might want to use function template type inference, like this:

```
template<typename T>
Base<T> CreateBase(T a)
{
  return new Base<T>(a);
}

// Call site avoids template clutter
auto base = CreateBase(2);
```