# C++ simplify constructor overloads

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, rvalue-reference

Say I am making a class `client`. I would like `client` to be able to be constructed with the following types:

```
client(const boost::network::uri::uri &, const boost::network::uri::uri &)
client(const std::string &, const std::string &)
client(const char *, const char *)
```

But... I would also like all the permutations...

```
client(const boost::network::uri::uri &, const boost::network::uri::uri &)
client(const std::string &, const std::string &)
client(const char * &, const char * &)
client(const boost::network::uri::uri &, const std::string &)
client(const std::string &, const boost::network::uri::uri &)
client(const boost::network::uri::uri &, const char * &)
client(const char * &, const boost::network::uri::uri &)
client(const std::string &, const char * &)
client(const char * &, const std::string &)
```

It may be assumed that my client class, stripped down for simplicity, looks like the following.

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/network.hpp>

#define HOST_URI "..."
#define AUTH_URI HOST_URI"..."

namespace bn = boost::network;

class client
{

private:

  const bn::uri::uri host_;

  const bn::uri::uri auth_;

public:

  client(const bn::uri::uri & host = const bn::uri::uri(HOST_URI),
         const bn::uri::uri & auth = const bn::uri::uri(AUTH_URI));

  client(const std::string & host = const std::string(HOST_URI),
         const std::string & auth = const std::string(AUTH_URI));

  client(const char * & host = HOST_URI,
         const char * & auth = AUTH_URI);

  client(const bn::uri::uri & host = const bn::uri::uri(HOST_URI),
         const std::string & auth = const std::string(AUTH_URI));

  client(const std::string & host = const std::string(HOST_URI),
         const bn::uri::uri & auth = const bn::uri::uri(AUTH_URI));

  client(const bn::uri::uri & host = const bn::uri::uri(HOST_URI),
         const char * & auth = AUTH_URI);

  client(const char * & host = HOST_URI,
         const bn::uri::uri & auth = const bn::uri::uri(AUTH_URI));

  client(const std::string && host = const std::string(HOST_URI),
         const char * & auth = AUTH_URI);

  client(const char * & host = HOST_URI,
         const std::string && auth = const std::string(AUTH_URI));

};
```

and currently defined as:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/network.hpp>

namespace bn = boost::network;

client::client(const bn::uri::uri & host,
               const bn::uri::uri & auth)
: host_(host), auth_(auth)
{
    ...
};

client::client(const std::string & host,
               const std::string & auth)
: client(bn::uri::uri(host), bn::uri::uri(auth)){}

client::client(const char * & host,
               const char * & auth)
: client(bn::uri::uri(host), bn::uri::uri(auth)){}

client::client(const bn::uri::uri & host,
               const std::string & auth)
: client(host, bn::uri::uri(auth)){}

client::client(const std::string & host,
               const bn::uri::uri & auth)
: client(bn::uri::uri(host), auth){}

client::client(const bn::uri::uri & host,
               const char * & auth)
: client(host, bn::uri::uri(auth)){}

client::client(const char * & host,
               const bn::uri::uri & auth)
: client(bn::uri::uri(host), auth){}

client::client(const std::string & host,
               const char * & auth)
: client(bn::uri::uri(host), bn::uri::uri(auth)){}

client::client(const char * & host,
               const std::string & auth)
: client(bn::uri::uri(host), bn::uri::uri(auth)){}
```

So my question is, what is the proper and easy way of doing this?
Granted, I did all the permutations this time by hand, but in the future I could have 3+ variables to permute, and this would get ugly, quick.

Comment: If `uri` has a constructor that accepts `std::string` or `char const*`, you will be able to get away with a lot fewer constructors.

Comment: @RSahu it does! Does c++ do some kind of implicit type initialization?

Comment: The compiler will use at most one user defined conversion. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator for additional details.

Comment: @RSahu Is this really considered a cast though? You're not casting string, char * types to uri, you're initializing a uri whose constructor takes those types...

Comment: The name of the URL is misleading. It talks about user defined conversions. Constructing an object of type `Type1` from an object of `Type2` where `Type1` has an appropriate constructor is under the same category.

Comment: The exact phrase is [Converting Constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor).

Comment: @RSahu Yeah, while I see the use of what you're saying, I can't see how it addresses my issue. Sure, in my definitions now I can delegate all overloaded constructor calls to the `client(uri::uri && host, uri::uri && auth)` constructor, but I am still left with a lot of overloads. This also brings up another issue, how do I delegate it to that constructor specifically, since, for example `client(const char * && host, const char * && auth) : client(host, auth){}` delegates to the string constructor by default instead of to the uri constructor?

Comment: Can you explain why you are accepting everything by non-const reference? (particularly the pointer versions). You don't seem to be changing the arguments.

Comment: If `uri` is a classname then `client(uri & host = uri(HOST_URI),` is illegal (non-const lvalue reference cannot bind to a temporary)

Comment: It was a copy mistake. Fixed. They are const.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a template:

```
#include <type_traits>

class client
{
    uri host_;
    uri auth_;

public:
    template <typename U, typename V,
              typename = typename std::enable_if<
                  std::is_constructible<uri, U&&>::value &&
                  std::is_constructible<uri, V&&>::value>::type>
    client(U && u, V && v)
    : host_(std::forward<U>(u))
    , auth_(std::forward<V>(v))
    { }

    // ...
};
```

Comment: To make the constructor a template, wouldn't I need to template the class?
Making just the constructor a template doesn't make much sense... [See this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960849/c-template-constructor)

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera: You linked a post without actually reading the first two sentences of the answer, methinks.

Comment: @BenVoigt No i did read it, however, the code above yields the following error: `Constructor cannot have a return type`, which leads me to believe it can't be done with a constructor as I said.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera: I think you may have misplaced a closing bracket.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera: The code I posted does what I mean. [Demo](http://ideone.com/x9KNCN). I edited it, though, to make it more self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

Since uri defines constructors that can take `string` as well as `const char *`, eliminate constructors whose parameters do not include those of uri type. This lets the [user-defined conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) of uri implicitly convert those types for you.

```
#define HOST_URI "..."
#define AUTH_URI HOST_URI"..."

class client
{
private:
  uri host_;

  uri auth_;

public:
  client(const uri & host = uri(HOST_URI),
         const uri & auth = uri(AUTH_URI));

  client(const char * host = HOST_URI,
         const char * auth = AUTH_URI);
};
```

-

```
client::client(const uri::uri & host,
               const uri::uri & auth)
: host_(host), auth_(auth)
{
    ...
};

client::client(const char * host,
               const char * auth)
: client(uri::uri(host), uri::uri(auth)){}
```

"How do I delegate it to that constructor specifically?"
Be explicit when using a delegating constructor.

```
client(const char * && host, const char * && auth) :
             client(uri(host), uri(auth)){}
```

or

```
client(const char * && host, const char * && auth) :
             client(string(host), string(auth)){}
```

Comment: Ok, so that answers one question that your previous observation brought up :P However, I am still left with the original question. How to permute all combinations of constructor parameters, and some problems I am having due to the parameters being of rvalue reference type.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera, my initial suggestion was to avoid `client` constructors with anything but `uri` as argument types. That will reduce the number of constructors you'll have to deal with.

Comment: Also, @Rsahu, `client c("", "");` gives an error: `no matching constructor for initialization of client`. So c++ is not performing the user-defined conversions for uri automatically like thought.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera: Does `uri` have an implicit conversion from `const char*` or only from `std::string`?  The C++ rules don't allow two implicit user-defined conversions in sequence on the same parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a single class which can take all of those three things as parameter. Your post didn't include enough details for me to write a concrete answer, but here is pseudocode:

```
struct input_helper
{
    input_helper(uri &u);
    input_helper(string &u);
    input_helper(char *u);

    // data members to hold the inputs, maybe other processing to bring them to a common type
};

// the constructor
client(input_helper host, input_helper auth);
```

Comment: "You can make a single class which can take all of those three things as parameter." Matt, by doing this, aren't you just delegating the responsibility of creating these overloaded constructors to such class?

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera yes, but then you only have 3 constructors to write (which will all be simple), plus the main `client` constructor, instead of 9.

Comment: Hmm, seems so overcomplicated xD
In reality I just needed to pass in 2 uri objects. But it simplifies my code everywhere else to be able to pass them in as these other types: `string` and `const char *` especially since such code would no longer need to include the header for uri.

Comment: If `uri` has a constructor that takes `const char *` and `string` too then you have no need for more than a single constructor taking two `uri` objects.

Comment: But I would have to explicitly change all of these instances of `const char *` and `string` parameters to client in my code by wrapping them in `uri` objects, and bringing in the uri header and namespace? Otherwise `client c("", "");` yields an error: `No matching constructor for initialization of 'client'.

Comment: It's a shame that there are no implicit conversions :)
C# and Java spoiled me too much.

Comment: Anyways, I ended up doing it that way, but instead of including the header and namespace, I just made a typedef `client::uri_type` and am find and replacing all instances to be wrapped by that type.

Comment: If `uri` has a constructor taking `char const *` then you can write `client c("", "")`.. I'm not sure what you are talking about w.r.t C# and Java because in C++ you can define whatever conversions you like when you are making a class

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't, it has one that takes a `std::string` and c++ only allows 0 or 1 implicit conversions. `const char *` needing 2. `uri(std::string(const char *))`

Comment: add a constructor that takes `const char *`

Comment: which leads us back to what I was doing originally: Adding multiple overloads for all levels of implicit conversion above 1 ;)

Comment: You only need a single constructor added to uri

Comment: This whole thread would be a lot less vague if you posted the definition of `uri` and also fixed the code in your post that doesn't compile