# Almost Always Use Auto rule with templated constructor?

Tags: c++, c++14

I have recently adopted the pattern of [Almost Always Auto](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) in C++14, but have come across a case that I can't figure out how to write using the `auto` syntax: templated constructors.

Say I have the class:

```
class my_type{
    public:
        template<typename T>
        my_type(){/* ... */}
};
```

I tried:

```
auto var = my_type<float>{};
```

Which, of course, doesn't work because that presumes `my_type` is a template and not its constructor.

then how could I use `auto` syntax to initialize this variable?

Comment: What type do you actually want the variable to be?

Comment: Oh, you're asking how to select that ctor, got it. How would you write this without using `auto`?

Comment: @Useless absolutely no idea, only just came across it now, actually. How would you do that?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode you can't, you need to deduce the template parameter from the arguments. If you could explain what that constructor is supposed to do, maybe we can suggest alternatives.

Comment: See for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3960849/212858). Now, this has nothing to do with `auto`, since you can't do this anyway.

Comment: @Useless I see that now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Although it isn't really about `auto`, there is a way to select templated ctors if you want to - you need to cheat, and give them an argument.

```
struct A {
private:
    template <typename T> struct TypeWrapper {};
    template <typename T> explicit A(TypeWrapper<T>) {}
public:
    template <typename T>
    static A make_A() {
        return A(TypeWrapper<T>{});
    }
};

int main() {
    auto i = A::make_A<int>();
    auto d = A::make_A<double>();
    auto r = A::make_A<A>();
    // etc. etc.
}
```

Comment: I really like this, but it would be better as a free function that is a `friend` of `A`