# Why does std::unique_lock use type tags to differentiate constructors?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-design, unique-lock, tag-dispatching

In C++11, the [`std::unique_lock` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/unique_lock) is overloaded to accept the type tags `defer_lock_t`, `try_to_lock_t`, and `adopt_lock_t`:

```
unique_lock( mutex_type& m, std::defer_lock_t t );
unique_lock( mutex_type& m, std::try_to_lock_t t );
unique_lock( mutex_type& m, std::adopt_lock_t t );
```

These are empty classes (type tags) [defined as follows](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_tag_t):

```
struct defer_lock_t { };
struct try_to_lock_t { };
struct adopt_lock_t { };
```

This allows the user to disambiguate between the three constructors by passing one of the [pre-defined instances](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_tag) of these classes:

```
constexpr std::defer_lock_t defer_lock {};
constexpr std::try_to_lock_t try_to_lock {};
constexpr std::adopt_lock_t adopt_lock {};
```

I am surprised that this is not implemented as an `enum`. As far as I can tell, using an `enum` would:

- be simpler to implement
- not change the syntax
- allow the argument to be changed at runtime (albeit not very useful in this case).
- (probably) could be inlined by the compiler with no performance hit

**Why does the standard library use type tags, instead of an `enum`, to disambiguate these constructors?** Perhaps more importantly, should I also prefer to use type tags in this situation when writing my own C++ code?

Comment: I don't really see why this would be "simpler to implement". And why go for "(probably) inlined" when you can have guaranteed no runtime overhead to select the correct behavior?

Comment: Probably because with tag structures like this, you can have three small and simple constructors, and the right one is picked by the compiler at compilation time, instead of having conditions and branches that are executed at run-time.

Comment: This may have been done on purpose, precisely so you cannot change behaviour at run time. This "potential feature" as you suggested on your 3rd point could turn out to be an optimization nightmare at compile time.

Comment: The earliest paper with this design I can find is [N2094](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2094.html), and it's got zero discussion on why tag types are chosen.

Comment: With enum approach you can't add/implement unique_lock( mutex_type& m, my_personal_lock_for_my_specific_usage t ). Unless you modify the std.

Comment: @T.C. +1 for the link.  We spent so much time arguing about cooperative thread cancellation that little else got discussed.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51881269/5740428

Answer (score 13):

### Tag dispatching

It is a **technique known as tag dispatching**. It allows the appropriate constructor to be called given the behaviour required by the client.

The reason for tags is that the **types used for the tags are thus unrelated** and will not conflict during overload resolution. Types (and not values as in the case of enums) are used to resolve overloaded functions. In addition, tags can be used to resolve calls that would otherwise have been ambiguous; in this case the tags would typically be based on some type trait(s).

Tag dispatching with templates means that only code that is required to be used given the construction is required to be implemented.

Tag dispatching allows for easier reading code (in my opinion at least) and simpler library code; the constructor won't have a `switch` statement and the invariants can be established in the initialiser list, based on these arguments, before executing the constructor itself. Sure, your milage may vary but this has been my general experience using tags.

[Boost.org](http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#tag_dispatching) has a write up on the tag dispatching technique. It has a history of use that seems to go back [at least as far as the SGI STL](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/iterator_tags.html).

### Why use it?

> Why does the standard library use type tags, instead of an enum, to disambiguate these constructors?

Types would be more powerful and flexible when used during overload resolution and the possible implementation than enums; bear in mind the enums were originally unscoped and limited in how they could be used (by contrast to the tags).

Additional noteworthy reasons for tags;

- Compile time decisions can be made over which constructor to use, and not runtime.
- Disallows more "hacky" code where a integer is cast to the enum type with a value that is not catered for - design decisions would need to be made out to handle this and then code implemented to cater for any resultant exceptions or errors.
- Keep in mind that the `shared_lock` and `lock_guard` also use these tags, but in the case of the `lock_guard`, only the `adopt_lock` is used. An enumeration would introduce more potential error conditions.

I think precedence and history also plays a role here. Given the wide spread use in the Standard Library and elsewhere; it is unlikely to change how situations, such as the original example, are implemented in the library.

> Perhaps more importantly, should I also prefer to use type tags in this situation when writing my own C++ code?

This is essentially a design decision. Both can and should be used to target the problems they solve. I have used tags to "route" data and types to the correct function; particular when the implementation would be incompatible at compile time and if there are any overload resolutions in play.

The Standard Library `std::advance` is often given as an example of how tag dispatching can be used to implement and optimise an algorithm based on traits (or characteristics) of the types used (in this case when the iterators are random access iterators).

It is a powerful technique when used appropriately and should not be ignored. If using enums, favour the newer scoped enums over the older unscoped ones.

Comment: Thanks for the Boost and SGI links! It makes sense to use type tags on `iterator` because: (1) the tag is a property of the type, (2) it doesn't make sense for the tag to change at runtime, and (3) it may need to be used elsewhere in generic programming. However, none of these properties are true for `unique_lock`. I suppose it's possible that it was implemented this way just to be consistent with other parts of the standard library.

Comment: @MichaelKoval *"I suppose it's possible that it was implemented this way just to be consistent with other parts of the standard library."* Such as the memory order for atomic operations? (which [uses an enumeration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)) ;)

Comment: If an enum were used, the obvious design decision would be that hacky values are UB. One Requires clause in the standard. No extra coding necessary.

Comment: @dyp for atomics, C compatibility is a concern.

Comment: @Michael. Another point is that the shared_lock and lock_guard also use tags, but in the case of the lock_guard, only the adopt_lock is used.

Comment: @T.C. I guess the C folks wouldn't want N*M functions with `_relaxed` etc. suffixes? Additionally, memory orders can be combined (e.g. acquire+release, and compare-exchange functions). So my analogy isn't that great.

Answer (score 0):

Using these tags enables you to take advantage of the type system of the language. This is closely related to template meta-programming. Simply speaking, using these tags allows the dispatch decision concerning which constructor to invoke to be made statically at compile time. This leaves room for compiler optimization, improves run-time efficiency, and makes template meta-programming with `std::unique_lock` easier. This is possible, because the tags are of different static types. With an `enum`, this cannot be done, for the value of an `enum` cannot be foreseen at compile time. Note that, using tags for differentiating purposes is a common template meta-programming technique. Just see those [iterator tags](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags) used by the standard library.

Comment: They could have used the enum as a template parameter

Comment: @James `enum` does not support inheritance (subclassing) and so on to fully exploit the type system of C++, which supports object-oriented programming. You see that the iterator tags form a class hierarchy.

Comment: Your point about tag dispatching is fine, but what do you mean by "the value of an enum cannot be foreseen at compile time." ?

Comment: @black It means the compiler knows that the parameter is an `enum`, but do not know the value of this `enum`.

Comment: Can you expand on that? Enumerators are `constexpr`, therefore the compiler does know their values.

Comment: @black The value of an enumerator is known at compile time, but not the value of an `enum` variable.

Answer (score -1):

The point is that if you want to add another function using `enum`, you should edit your `enum`, then rebuild all projects, which use your functions and `enum`. In addition there will be one function taking enum as argument and using `switch` or something. This will bring excess code into your application.

Otherwise if you use overloaded functions with tags, you can easily add another tag and add another overloaded function, without touching old ones. This is more back-compatible.

Comment: As far as I know the C++ standard doesn't may *any* guarantees about ABI compatibility. Adding a new constructor *probably* won't break ABI compatibility. But, then again, the same is true of adding a value to an enum.

Comment: Adding a new constructor technically requires you to recompile the existing code anyway. It's an ODR violation otherwise.

Comment: I mean that you should edit `enum` in one file, so as function. But using tags you can implement new functions in another files or even libraries.

Comment: Of course the main point is that you need only one constructor at the time. So the compiler will choose only one you need. Otherwise there will be a `switch` on the runtime, and excess code you don't need.

Comment: The enum could be a template parameter

Comment: @James: I don't see how the `enum` could be a template parameter. As far as I know, it's not possible to explicitly specify template parameters to a constructor (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3960925/111426). There is also no way to infer the value of a non-type template parameter.

Comment: @MichaelKoval well, you can deduce a non-type parameter with a tag type...and then we are back to square one.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect it was optimization. Notice that using a type (as is) the correct version is selected at compile time. As you point out using an `enum` is (potentially) selected in some conditional statement (maybe a `switch`) at run-time.

In many implementations locks are acquired and released at extremely high frequency and maybe designers thought with branch prediction and the implied memory synchronization events that might be a significant issue.

The flaw in my argument (which you also point out) is that the constructor is likely to be inline and it is likely that the condition would be optimized away anyway.

Notice that using 'dummy' parameters is the closest possible analogue to actually providing named constructors.

Answer (score -1):

This method is called tag dispatching (I may be wrong). Enum type with different values is just one type in compile time and enum values can't be used to overload constructor. So with enum it will be one constructor with switch statement in it. Tag dispatching is equivalent to switch statement in compile time. Each tag type specify: what this constructor would do, how it will try to acquire the lock. You should use type tags, when you want to make decision in compile time and use enum to make decision in run-time.

Answer (score -1):

Because, in `std::unique_lock<Mutex>`, you don't want to *force* `Mutex` to have a `lock` or `try_lock` method if it may never need to be called.

If it accepted an `enum` parameter, then both of those methods would need to be present.

Comment: A mutex without `lock()` is pretty useless, and `unique_lock` requires `BasicLockable` anyway. You may have a better argument for `try_lock()`, though.