# static_assert to check value in non-template class's template constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, static-assert

So, I'm looking for a way to cause a compile-time error if the value used in declaring the object is equal to another value (don't wish to use C's `assert` macro).

Yes, I know why the problem occurs... The compiler was quite clear when he/she complained `expression did not evaluate to a constant`.

I also don't want to make my entire class a template. Is there a little miracle workaround that I'm missing?

```
#include <iostream>

class test
{
private:
    template<class T, class T2>
    using both_int = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value && std::is_integral<T2>::value>;
private:
    int _a, _b;
public:

    template<class T, class T2 = T, class = both_int<T, T2>>
    constexpr test(const T &a, const T2 &b = 1)
        : _a(a), _b(b)
    {
        static_assert(b != 0, "Division by zero!");
    }
};

int main()
{
    test obj(1, 0); //ERROR

    test obj2(0, 1); //OK

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Make `b` a template parameter of the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
struct test {
private:
  constexpr test(int a, int b) {}
public:
  template<int b>
  static test construct(int a) {
    static_assert(b != 0, "not zero failed");
    return test(a, b);
  }     
};

int main()
{
   test foo = test::construct<1>(1);
   test foo = test::construct<0>(1);//compile error
}
```

You need static constructor, because of there is no way to specify parameters of
template constructor, see [C++ template constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960849/c-template-constructor)