# Dependent types in c++, a non zero type

Tags: c++, types

Let's say this the bare bone for a non zero-able type.

```
template<typename T>
struct NonZero {
    T val;
};
```

My question is if it's possible to make a constructor for `NonZero` which to take a literal of type `T` and statically check if it's non-zero and then assigns it to `val`.

```
NonZero<int> n( 0 ); // compilation error
NonZero<int> n( 1 ); // ok
```

Or is there a better way to archieve a non zero type?

Comment: To my understanding, the specific implementations can be provided only by template specialization; is that what is desired?

Comment: I was wondering if there was an easier way, because `NonZero<int> n( var )` should also be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option would be to check a value for being zero in `constexpr` constructor:

```
template<typename T>
struct NonZero {
    const T value;
    constexpr NonZero(const T val) :
        value(val != 0 ? val : throw std::runtime_error("should be non-zero"))
    {}
};
```

Usage:

```
NonZero<int> v(1);            // OK
NonZero<int> v2(0);           // Compiles OK, but throws in run-time
constexpr NonZero<int> v3(1); // OK
constexpr NonZero<int> v4(0); // Compilation error
```

This method is only applicable to `constexpr` variables, but looks much more straightforward.

Also, instead of using a `struct` with `constexpr` constructor, you could use a `constexpr` function or a user-defined literal, with exactly the same idea.

Comment: I'm just getting an error in gcc saying `expression '<throw-expression>' is not a constant-expression`. Do you have an idea of the problem?

Comment: I'm so stupid, nevermind my comment, of course there is a compilation error when the variable is constructed with a 0. Thank you anyway, it was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Sherushe You're welcome. It was a wonderful question to answer.

Answer (score 5):

Since the value is known at the compile time, you could make it a template argument and use `std::enable_if`:

```
template<typename T, T x>
struct NonZero {
    const static std::enable_if_t<x != T(0), T> value = x;
};
```

Usage:

```
int x = NonZero<int, 1>::value; // OK
int x2 = NonZero<int, 0>::value;// Compilation error
```

Comment: Thank you, I noticed a was a bit vague in my question. A constructor with an lvalue int was also something needed.

Comment: @Sherushe Then looks like my another answer is a good idea to try.

Answer (score 1):

Just thought of another approach, which will provide you a constructor which takes a value as an argument.

The core idea is to make the constructor templated and pass the value as a template argument. Unfortunately, it's impossible to do this in a straightforward way, but we can use a workaround from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960849/c-template-constructor):

```
template<typename T>
struct NonZero {
    const T value;

    template<T x>
    NonZero(std::integral_constant<std::enable_if_t<x != T(0), T>, x>) : value(x) {
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
auto v  = NonZero<int>(std::integral_constant<int, 1>()); // OK
auto v2 = NonZero<int>(std::integral_constant<int, 0>()); // Compilation error
```