# Constructor with non-type template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960849/c-template-constructor) it's stated that it's impossible to just directly use template arguments for class constructor, because if you write something like

```
struct S{
    template<typename T>
    S() { ... }
}
```

Then you have no way of calling this constructor. However, there're some workarounds to make this work, for example, through template argument deduction.

But all of these workarounds I know are for type arguments only. So, the question is

**Are there any workarounds to make this work for non-type template arguments?**

```
struct S{
    template<int x>
    S() { ... }
}
```

I'm interested in solutions which should work in modern C++ (C++17 standard, including all TS), as this is a theoretical rather than practical question.

Comment: Non-type template parameters have always been deducible given a proper parameter list. This happens a lot for `std::size_t` parameters when given an array. Yakk's `tag` answer applies equally.

Comment: You could have `template<int x> S(std::integral_constant<int, x>);`

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. Could you please write it a bit more in detail in form of an answer?

Comment: While the accepted answer provides a technically correct solution to your question, I don't see how using `S s(val<5>{});` is better than using `S s<5>{};`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But all of these workarounds I know are for type arguments only

None of the workarounds are type-specific - the point is to stick something in the constructor that can be deduced. So if we want a type, we do something like:

```
template <class T> struct tag { };

struct S {
    template <class T>
    S(tag<T>);
};
```

and if we want an `int`, we do the same thing:

```
template <int I> struct val { };

struct S {
    template <int I>
    S(val<I>);
};
```

For values, you don't even need to come up with your own tag type - you can piggy-pack on top of `std::integral_constant`.