# Templated constructor not accessible in struct

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, c++17, iostream

Templated constructor is not accessible in struct.  I would like to allow for non-templated construction still, if possible.  If its not possible I would like to understand what wall this actually is in the language, if any..

The error is this:
**Expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction**

It's a syntax error.  How you construct with a template is name(args), and that is exactly what:

`A a = A<short>(1);` ... is doing, right?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int i;
    A() : i(0) { }
    
    template <typename T>
    A(T i) : i(int(i)) { }

    void print() {
         std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a = A<short>(1);
    a.print();
    return 0;
}
```

-- EDIT --

Adding the #1 problem I ran into at first.  The answer came quick but theres a bit more nuance here.  Let me describe it better.

```
struct A {
    std::function<int(int)> fn;

    template <typename T>
    A() {
        fn = [](int i) {
            /// merely using T somewhere in this lambda
            return int(T(i));
        };
    }
};

int main(int c, const char *v[]) {
    A a = A<int>();
}
```

I originally stated it must have the default constructor but I wasn't actually needing it that way.  I am, however not directly referencing the template param in any argument and I know why that must be what I'm stuck with?

-- EDIT 3 --

I simply needed a class-mode template setup in my case.  The reason I was a bit stubborn was the need to keep a bit of code out of the header.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ template constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960849/c-template-constructor)

Comment: You have to add some parameters to make it possible to perform type deduction; or make `A` template from the beginning.

Answer (score 5):

The templated constructor will be selected if you construct A from a short explictly

```
#include <iostream>

struct A 
{
    int i;
    A() : i(0) { }

    // i(int(i)) { } <== do NOT use "C" style casts in C++
    template <typename T>
    A(T v) :
        i{ static_cast<int>(v) } 
    {
        std::cout << "using templated constructor\n";
    }


    void print() {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    A a{ short{1} }; // construct a from a short
    a.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`A` is a non-template class, so you can't specify template argument for it like `A<short>`. And there's no way to specify template argument for constructor template; template argument could only be deduced from constructor argument.

So you can

```
A a = A(1); // T will be deduced as int
            // if pass a short like static_cast<short>(1) T will be deduced as short
```

Or just

```
A a(1); // T will be deduced as int
        // if pass a short like static_cast<short>(1) T will be deduced as short
```

Comment: Looks like I may have to edit this one.  I'm doing a bit more in my use-case than I described.

Comment: No but by explicitly constructing a from a short the templated constructor will be selected

Comment: Well my problem is I am trying to do this with an app class constructor, with a View type given as a template param.  In this case, it's passed by requirement with a lambda being created with its use.   Still, I cannot pass the <View>

Comment: @Kalen Is there any implicit conversion required? From lambda to <View> type. Implicit conversion won't be considered in template argument deduction, so you have to perform the conversion explicitly before pass to the constructor.