# Which member functions can be templated in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17, member-functions, function-templates

I was asked a question

> Which class functions can be templated in C++? (constructor, destructor, const, static)

Did I understand correctly that all member functions (except destructor) can be templated?

##### Constructor / destructor

```
class A {
public:
    template<class T>
    A(T t) {
        cout << t << endl; 
    }

    /*
    template<class U>
    ~A() {  // error: destructor cannot be declared as a template
        cout << "Destructor\n";
    }*/

};


int main() {
    A a(5);
}
```

##### Static function

Yes, it can be template.

```
class A {
public:
    template< typename T>
    static double foo( vector<T> arr );

};

template< typename T>
double A::foo( vector<T> arr ){ cout << arr[0] << endl; }

int main() {
    A a;
    A::foo<int>({1, 2, 3});
}
```

##### Non-constant / constant member function

Yes.

```
class A {
public:
    template< typename T>
    double foo( vector<T> arr ) const {
        cout << arr[0] << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.foo<int>({1, 2, 3});
}
```

Comment: You can only have a template constructor when implicit argument deduction can be used, not in all cases: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960849/c-template-constructor

Comment: A class can only have one destructor, and a template is the means of automatically generating a family of functions.   So having a templated destructor is not allowed (essentially because it would be pointless and potentially misleading to have one).   A class can have as many (static or non-static) other member functions as judged appropriate to its design - so they can (if appropriate) be templated.

Comment: I also tried to define a template cast operator. It works. But it seems you can not define a template cast to another type (like this: `template<typename T> operator double() const { return (double)T(); }`)

Comment: @Caduchon Curiously, you [can in fact](https://godbolt.org/z/f8GezvafY) define a templated conversion operator like this - but there doesn't appear to be any syntax to actually call it. So it's mostly of academic interest.

Comment: @Caduchon the more sensible template cast operator is `template<typename T> operator T() const`

Comment: @Peter a class template can certainly have multiple destructor definitions with different `requires` clauses.

Comment: @WeijunZhou   Sure.   But a class template is not a class, it is a recipe for generating a family of classes.   Any class that is instantiation/specialisation of a class template can still only have one destructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, any member function can be *templated*, since that term includes member functions of class templates (or of member classes of class templates, or local classes in function templates, *etc.*) that can of course use the template parameters for whatever enclosing template.  The real question is which members can be function templates (and thus not functions at all).

The answer is simple: any member function that is not a (prospective) **destructor** and not **`virtual`** can instead be a function template.  (Constructor templates and conversion function templates can’t be invoked with **explicit** template arguments, so those have to be deduced.)

Note, though, that neither a function template nor a specialization of one can count as certain **special** member functions, even if it can be used in their stead (thanks to suppressing the implicit declaration or being a better match):

```
struct A {
  template<class=int>
  A(int=0);          // #1, not a default constructor
  template<class T>
  A(T&);             // #2, not a copy constructor
  template<class T>
  A& operator=(T&);  // #3, not a copy-assignment operator
} a,         // calls #1
  b(a),      // calls #2
  &r=(a=b);  // calls #3
```

`A` still has defaulted copy/move operations here because none of these interfere.

Answer (score 0):

All class methods ***except*** the destructor and ***copy constructors*** (and move constructors?) can be defined as class member templates.

- Custom constructors
- Instance methods
- Static methods
- Operators (including assignment and conversion)

Other considerations:

- There are some restrictions on the types of *classes* which can have member templates (locally defined classes cannot).
- Class member templates cannot be virtual nor can they override virtual functions in a base class.
- There are also some tricky details of class member template lookup to consider.
- Technically you could (probably?) declare the default constructor to be a member template, but it would not make sense to do so.

See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_template