# How to pass a template parameter to an object without calling its member functions?

Tags: c++, object, templates

I can pass a template parameter to an object's member function, but not to the object itself.
Is this possible at all?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Logger {
public:

    Logger& operator()(int t) {
        cerr << "(tag " << t << ") ";
        return *this;
    }

    Logger& operator<<(const string &s) {
        cerr << s << endl;
        return *this;
    }

    template<int t> Logger& Tag() {
        cerr << "(tag " << t << ") ";
        return *this;
    }

    Logger() {}

    template<int t> Logger() {
        cerr << "(tag " << t << ") ";
    }
};

int main() {
    {
        Logger log;
        log(2) << "World";
        log(3) << "World";
        log.Tag<2>() << "Template 1";
        log<2> << "Template 2";        // <-- error
    }
}
```

This is the error message (from GCC 13.2):

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('Logger' and 'int')
        log<2> << "Template 2";
        ~~~^~
```

What I would like to achieve is to have log<2> and log.Tag<2> behave in the same way.

Comment: Short answer: Nope.  In order to pass a parameter to `log`, `log` must be a template.

Comment: You can make a (global) variable template: `template <int N> Logger log;`. In it, pass `N` either to the constructor or make it a template parameter of `Logger`.

Comment: @NathanOliver - Isn't it enough for the member function to be a template? Consider that `log` does not know about the template parameter during its definition.

Comment: What do you expect `log<2>` to mean?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - N is unknown during object definition. It is specified to the object once it is already defined and being used.

Comment: `log<2>` tries to instantiate a template called `log` with non-type parameter with the value of `2`.  There is no way to get that syntax to work without making `log` a template.

Comment: @molbdnilo - I would like `log<2>` to be equivalent to `log.Tag<2>()`.

Comment: If `Tag` weren't a template, would you expect `log` to be equivalent to `log.Tag()`?

Comment: @NathanOliver - Could you please make an example? The reason I did not make `Logger` a template class is because I do not know the value of `t` at that time, and this value can change for different calls: `log<2>`, `log<3>`, ...

Comment: @molbdnilo - Yes.

Comment: If that value changes, why not just use what you already have with `log(2)`?  What does making a template do for you that the non-template version doesn't?

Comment: @NathanOliver - I want to use a template so that I can be sure that part of the process takes place at compile time. Using `operator()` this can either happen or not, depending on the compiler optimization settings, and is not guaranteed.

Comment: @Pietro But they aren't equivalent. To be honest, that is a pretty odd expectation.

Comment: @molbdnilo - `log()` and `log<>` are not equivalent, but `log.Tag<>()` and `log<>` are.

Comment: *"N is unknown during object definition. It is specified to the object once it is already defined and being used."* Yes, and? I didn't suggest otherwise.

Comment: @Pietro Why do you think they're equivalent when you know that one of them is even syntactically invalid? Why would `log` in itself be equivalent to a call to any particular member function?

Comment: *'but `log.Tag<>()` and `log<>` are'* – you mean, you *want* them to be equivalent. Bad luck, though, there's no such thing as a compile time `operator<>`, and the second form just results in invalid syntax (which has already been mentioned before).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - If that is the case, could you please answer with an example? Thanks

Comment: @molbdnilo - OK, let me correct myself: I would like `log.Tag<>()` and `log<>` to be equivalent, as @Aconcagua pointed out.

Comment: the question is unclear. Title and body are asking different contradicting questions. Title ".. to an object .." text "... but not to the object itself." !?!? Moreover it is unclear what you expect from `log<2> << "Template 2";`. Wrong code is terrible at explaining what it should do. You need to tell us what that line should do.

Comment: Maybe I could define my own `operator<>` that behaves like `.Tag<>()`...

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai - The question is ".. to an object without ..", so I see no contradiction. What I would like to achieve is to have `log<2>` and `log.Tag<2>` behave in the same way.

Comment: "... to an object without calling its member functions" I understand as passing a tempalte parameter to an object. And doing that without calling its member functions. Either way, it is not clear

Comment: why do you want to write `log<2>` when you  actually want to call `Tag<2>` ? It sounds like you are trying to make up syntax that isnt C++ syntax. If you want to call `Tag<2>` you can do that already.

Comment: the presence of the template constructor is somewhat suspicious. Do you want it to be called somewhere in the process of making `log<2>` do something?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai - That is what I mean, without *explicitely* calling a member function, e.g. through an operator. What I am trying to do is simply syntactic sugar, the implementation of `Tag<2>` is correct. This example is simplified, but it explains my objective.

Comment: @Pietro `Logger` is not a class template. So `log<2>` is just invalid syntax. There's no way around this.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai - The template constructor was just an attempt, but it is not what I intended. As I wrote, the implementation must do exactly what `Tag<2>` does, with different (more compact) syntax.

Comment: Also c++ doesn't allow this. See [Is it possible to have a constructor template with no parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960849/is-it-possible-to-have-a-constructor-template-with-no-parameters)

Comment: syntax is not designed to minimize typing, but to maximize clarity. `log.Tag<2>()` is how you call the member template called `Tag` by instantiating it with argument `2`. Different syntax can be achieved via preprocessing the code, but would be considered obfuscation. What you want cannot be done in C++ (but trivially outside of C++). Tbh, I still do not understand what your question actually is, because you were already told that C++ doesnt work that way, (and the way to generate code to get from your  syntax to actual c++ syntax should also be clear)

Comment: If what I am trying to achieve is not possible, please write it in an answer. If an alternative approach can get close, it will be welcome.

Comment: Minimising typing might be convenient for the person who writes the code, but can hide important information and in some cases get a night mare for those reading the code – so careful in general. Maybe less in given case, and an alternative that might get somewhat close could be a *macro*: `#define logT(INDEX) log.Tag<INDEX>()` which could be used as `logT(2) << "whatever"`. Looks the same as the `operator()(int)` approach, but evaluates the argument at compile time as being mapped to the template variant.

Comment: Hopefully you really just minimised your example, because if it is as simple as given here I'd just keep the `operator()(int)` and throw the rest away; and depending on what the parameter stands for you might want to replace the `int` with some more clearly defined `enum` or `enum class` to produce more obvious/better readable code (the enum stuff might apply even if you keep your tags...).

Comment: @Aconcagua - At this point I have two options: use the preprocessor (which I was doing everything possible to avoid), or use a completely different approach, i.e. moving from `streams` to `std::format` as suggested by @HolyBlackCat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to achieve the `log<i> << ...` syntax is to make `log` a variable template. Note that this will break `log << ...` and `log.Foo()` syntax.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Logger
{
    int loglevel = 0;
  public:
    Logger(int loglevel) : loglevel(loglevel) {}

    Logger& operator<<(const std::string &s)
    {
        std::cerr << loglevel << "->" << s << '\n';
        return *this;
    }
};
template <int N> Logger log(N);

int main()
{
    log<2> << "blah";
}
```

This would give you N "loggers", one per log level, so they should probably hold pointers to the one single underlying logger.

I don't think this is a good idea overall. Firstly, too much effort for a tiny bit of syntax sugar. And second, in the modern day you should probably design your logger around `std::format`, which means all your logging statements become function calls, such as:

```
log(i, "format", args...);
log<i>("format", args...);
```

And this call syntax is trivial to implement.

Comment: The option to have N loggers is interesting, but not worth in my case. I may consider the syntax used by `std::format` instead, which will also bring performance improvements on its own.